# Force Data Types With scipy.signal Methods

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing, execution

I'm measuring the performance (execution time) of various scipy functions (scipy.signal.lfilter, scipy.signal.filtfilt, etc.) when using various depths of floats and integers.

How do I force the desired numeric type and depth?  Let's use lfilter as an example:

```
    B, A = iirfilter(some params)
    ZI = lfiltic(B, A, Y0)
    Y, D = lfilter(B, A, X, zi = ZI)
```

Where would I want to use, for instance, .astype(np.float32) in order to be sure that lfilter indeed processes internally in float32 (if it's possible)?

I'm aware there is much discussion about which runs faster between floats and ints, and I believe the consensus is it varies with the CPU model. With this in mind, I'm performing these tests on the exact CPU which will eventually process the "real world" data, namely an Intel Core i7-8750H.

Comment: Have you studied the `lfilter` code?  There's quite a bit of python setup code.

Comment: @hpauij indeed there is some python setup code, but I'm using an IIR filter where len(A)  > 1, so I bypass all of that and go straight to the one-line call at the bottom.  That call ventures off into C(?) stuff, so I don't know what's happening.  Now, I'm also looking at the lfilter_zi() and lfiltic() code.  Noted, that the latter forces np.float64 on a variable, and presumably that type propagates through the code.

Comment: 'C' math libraries are compiled for a limited mix of types, often with a different function for `float`, `double` etc.  So the Python interface code has to choose one, and translate your input/output dtypes accordingly.